# Console says scanner is closed , I need it to reopen. Java error

Tags: java

Here is all my code so far, I am not sure what the problem is. This is a grocery receipt program is supposed to handle exceptions and the user can update the list of products in a file. The program will search through the file and spit out a receipt to a file called receipts in my computer of all products "purchased".

Here is the code:

```
package groceries;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Project2_ReceiptPrinterV2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // Declaring all of the variables and containers that the program needs

    File inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\camer\\Desktop\\CECS 274\\Pricelist.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    String itemRegex = "([\\w |\\W]+[s|\\w])\\s+(\\w[\\w |\\W]+\\S)\\s+([\\w |\\W]+\\s[\\w]+\\w)"; 
    String regexFull = "([\\w |\\W]+[s|\\w])\\s+(\\w[\\w |\\W]+\\S)\\s+([\\w |\\W]+\\s[\\w]+\\w)\\s+([\\w |\\W]+)";

    Pattern fullItemPattern = Pattern.compile(regexFull, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE); 
    Pattern noPricePattern = Pattern.compile(itemRegex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher fileMatcher; 
    Matcher userMatcher;

    System.out.println("Enter the output filename: "); // Create the file name 
    String outFileName = userInput.nextLine();
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\camer\\Desktop\\Receipts\\" + outFileName +".txt");
    StringBuilder returnedString = new StringBuilder();
    final int maxLen = 60;

    ArrayList<Item> products = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    String product;
    int holder;
    boolean inList = false;
    double total = 0.0;
    int numberOfItems;
    String quantifier;
    String itemPrice;
    boolean runProgram = true;
    String ProductEntry = "";
    String ProductEntryName = "";
    String ProductQuality = "";
    double ProductEntryPrice = 0;

    // Starting the user input loop


    while (runProgram) {
        System.out.println("Enter a product to add to your cart:\nEnter 'done' when finished.");
        input = userInput.nextLine().trim();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            userMatcher = noPricePattern.matcher(input);
        }
        try {
            if (userMatcher.find()) {
                while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {

                    fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);

                    fileMatcher = fullItemPattern.matcher(fileReader.nextLine());

                    if (fileMatcher.find()) {
                        if (fileMatcher.group(1).trim().equals(userMatcher.group(1)) && fileMatcher.group(2).trim().equals(userMatcher.group(2)) && fileMatcher.group(3).trim().equals(userMatcher.group(3))){
                            product = fileMatcher.group(1) + " " + fileMatcher.group(2).trim();
                            Item itemHolder = new Item(product, Double.parseDouble(fileMatcher.group(4)), fileMatcher.group(3).trim());


                            if (products.contains(itemHolder)) {
                                // Adding the first product
                                products.get(products.indexOf(itemHolder)).incQuantity();
                            }
                            else {
                                // Adding multiple products after that
                                products.add(itemHolder);
                            }
                            // User feedback that the item was added
                            inList = true;
                            System.out.println("Product added!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!inList) {
                // If there is no such item in the file
                throw new IOException();
            }
            else {
                inList = false;
            }
            // Resetting the fileReader for each new item
            fileReader.close();
            fileReader = new Scanner(inFile);

        }
        catch(IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error! Selected product is not listed in file!");
            System.out.println("Would you like to correct your entry?");
            String UserResponse = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            if(UserResponse.equals("yes")) {
            }
            if (UserResponse.equals("no")) {
                System.out.println("Would you like to add your selected entry in to the file");
                String UserResponse2 = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                    if(UserResponse2.equals("yes")) {}
                        try {
                            File PriceList = new File("C:\\Users\\camer\\Desktop\\CECS 274\\Pricelist.txt");
                            FileWriter NewEntry = new FileWriter(PriceList, true);
                            BufferedWriter added = new BufferedWriter(NewEntry);
                            added.newLine();
                            System.out.println("Adding selected product into file now ...");
                            System.out.println("Enter Product name: ");
                            ProductEntry = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                            ProductEntryName = ProductEntry.split(" ")[0];
                            ProductQuality = ProductEntry.split(" ")[1];
                            ProductEntryName = ProductEntryName + " " + ProductQuality;
                            System.out.println("Enter the Size/Weight of the product");
                            String ProductEntrySize = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                            System.out.println("Enter the price of the product");
                            ProductEntryPrice = userInput.nextDouble();
                            String NewProduct = ProductEntryName + " " +  ProductEntrySize + " " + ProductEntryPrice;
                            added.write(NewProduct);
                            System.out.println("Product added!\n");
                            added.close();



                     }
                     catch (IOException error) {
                         error.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     if(UserResponse2.equals("no")) {
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 }

        finally {

                // Outputting to the file
                for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i ++) {
                    outFile.print("_");
                }
                outFile.println();
                outFile.println("Java Market");
                outFile.println("242 W Santa Cruz St");
                outFile.println("San Pedro, CA");
                outFile.println("90731");
                outFile.println();
                outFile.println("Product                                              Subtotal");

                // Looping through products and processing multiples, formatting strings, and outputting to the file
                for (Item a : products) {
                    buffer.add(a.toString());
                    total += a.getTotalPrice();
                }

                Collections.sort(buffer);
                for (String b : buffer) {
                    outFile.println(b);
                }
                //outFile.println();

                for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i ++) {
                    outFile.print("_");
                }
                // Skipping lines and printing the formatted total
                outFile.println();
                outFile.println();
                outFile.println();
                outFile.printf("Your total is: $%.2f", total);
                outFile.println();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i ++) {
                    outFile.print("_");
                }
                // Closing the out file and file reader after everything is done
                outFile.close();
                fileReader.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Dude, not trying to be unkind, but this code is a mess.  You should not be handling large amounts of code in the `catch` block.  - Why are you reopening the same file in a loop.  Also consider using methods, to split your code into understandable blocks.  This is hard to ready now and will be hell to debug in the future when it is not fresh in you brain.

Comment: Its okay, I am a intro programmer to the language and my professor assigned this project and our whole class is struggling. Sorry...

Comment: It also helps to break long lines to keep them under about 80 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `fileReader` to a new `Scanner` in the `while` loop every time you read a line. What you want to do is assign it at the top of the `try` block. That way, it will be closed at the end of the block. Also, if that is what you want to do, then remove the assignment at the top. Additionally, you can have Java close it automatically like this:

```java
try (Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(inFile)) {
    ...
```

One other note is that it is generally faster (and maybe easier) to use a `BufferedReader` rather than a `Scanner`. I believe the only difference in your case would be using `readLine()` rather than `nextLine()`. You can also check for a `null` line instead of `fileReader.hasNextLine()`. That would look like this:

```java
try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile))) {
    ...
```

Note that if you use this, you should not declare or assign `fileReader` anywhere else, or close it, as it is automatically closed when used as a `try` block resource.

Comment: Ok! Hey that worked, just what I needed so it reads properly. Now I just need to see why the product did not display in my receipt after i added it to the file.